# Some programs in Windows 10 go straight into background

Tags: windows-10

My problem is that when I want to run some programs (e.g. Tenoshare Partition Manager, Active@ Partition Manager, Recuva) they seem not to work --- nothing is showing up. But when I check the Task Manager they are there but only run as a background processes. How to run them in the foreground and be able to actually use them as intended?

This behaviour is only seen for some of the programs.

[Task Manager screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDRth.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How long are you waiting for the programs to run? What are your system specs? What does Event Viewer say? Have you reinstalled the programs doing this, checked for updates to them, etc? Why are you running these particular programs (partition managers and file recovery programs), is there some other problem your computer is experiencing you're trying to solve?